# Exception Due to referring struts.dtd file from internet/local

Tags: java, struts2, struts

From morning facing Exception while running struts2 apps....application was working yesterday

There's a problem in loading some struts2-jquery jar even though they exist in WEB-INF/lib

After browsing I got some solution to make change in struts.xml `<!DOCTYPE ....>`

like changing

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE struts SYSTEM "../dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
```

or

```
<!DOCTYPE struts SYSTEM "struts-2.0.dtd">
```

For local referencing struts.dtd but none of these working..

Exception on console :

```
Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/D:/.........plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/XXXXXXXX/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:25:88
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:360)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:403)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:273)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:254)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:372)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4584)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5257)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: Error building results for action getGroups in namespace  - action - file:/D:/T....plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/XXXXXXX/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:25:88
```

Answer (score 2):

This has been resolved and was due to a change in Apache project publishing mechanisms.

For details :

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3979